# Python and function within function recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Say I have something like this sample code.

```
def foo(n):
   def bar():
      return -1
   if n = 0:
      return 0
   else:
      return foo(n+bar())
```

I assume it creates a new instance of bar every time foo is recursively called. However this seems like something that could be optimized in python (or any other language) but I was unable to find anything stating if it has been optimized for that.

The reasoning I have bar defined in foo is I'm trying to hide bar from the user and python's _bar() or __bar() of "please sir don't use this dear user" is annoying me as I was trained in non scripting languages.

Comment: The real problem is that you're trying to hide stuff from the user. That's just not the Python way of doing things. If you want to make a function "private", don't include its name in the `__all__` global variable of your module. Python doesn't have "real" private functions. If a user wants to access `bar`, there's no point in slapping them and saying they can't do that.

Comment: `The reasoning I have bar defined in foo is I'm trying to hide bar from the user and python's _bar() or __bar() of "please sir don't use this dear user" is annoying me as I was trained in non scripting languages.` If you're using an interpreted language they could just get to your code anyway. Why do you feel the need to hide it so thoroughly.

Comment: Encapsulation. If a user could go into a private method and modify it without going through the designed for route suddenly the flow of the program is no longer makes sense. EI people like going "oh it's a counter. I want it done twice as fast as I'm not clear why I'm waiting" not realizing it's not simply a counter.

Comment: @user2309351: Yes, indeed, if a user does mess with your implementation he might (or not) break something. So what ? How is this _your_ problem ? Stupid people will do stupid things anyway, so why bother ? Anyway: Python is not designed to be idiot-proof, so don't waste your time fighting the language, just use it the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def` is an executable statement in Python (and so is `class`).  A new function object for `bar` is created each time `foo()` is invoked, but it's pretty trivial cost.  It just retrieves the compiled code object, and wraps it in a new function object.  People stress over this waaaay too much ;-)  In general, it's necessary to do this in order for closures to work right, and to capture appropriate default arguments.  You're right that in many cases this *could* be optimized a bit, but the CPython implementation doesn't bother.